# Cheerio. Не удается получить данные внутри тела TRY после обработки ошибки другой функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Есть такой код:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
let data = null;



const parseNewCorporations = async (iter) => {
  
  let link2 = 'https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/' + iter.finanzen_net + '-aktie';
  try{
    await axios.get(link2)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
        
        let html = res;
        
        $ = cheerio.load( html, { decodeEntities: false } );
        let bigData = iter;
        
        let price = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap').text();
        let currency = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap span').text();
        price = price.replace(currency, '').replace(',', '.');
      })
  }
  
  catch(e){
    console.log(e.message, ', id =', iter.id, ", finanzen_net = "+iter.finanzen_net);
    await getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv(iter);
  }
};



const getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv = async (iter) => {
  
  //console.log('111', iter); // **здесь код срабатывает корректно**
  
  let link = 'https://www.finanzen.net/bilanz_guv/'+ iter.finanzen_net;
  
  try{
    await axios.get(link)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
        
        console.log('getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv', iter);
        // **здесь код срабатывает НЕ корректно**
        
      })
  }
  
  catch(e){
    if(e.message == 'Request path contains unescaped characters'){
      console.log('Request path contains unescaped characters');
      console.log({paramSubLink: iter.finanzen_net, corporations_id: iter.id});
    }
    else{
      console.log('paramCorporationsId: ', iter.id);
      //console.log('err- ', e);
    }
  }
};



function getApiData(){
  
  // get request
      return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/invest/daily.php" , {
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}



async function new_corporations() {
    data = await getApiData();
    let ii = 1;
    for (let iter of data.new_corporations) {
        //await parseNewCorporations(iter);
        
        ii++;
        await setTimeout(function(){
            parseNewCorporations(iter);
        }, ii*3000);
        

    }
    //console.log(arrayCurrency);
}


new_corporations();
```

После вызова функции `parseNewCorporations()` срабатывает исключение `catch()` в результате которого
в консоли можно увидеть соотвествующие сообщения.
Проблема заключается в том что во время появления этой ошибки необходимо запустить следующую функцию `getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv()` с параметром `iter`, и внутри тела `try{}` необходимо этот параметр получить, чего сделать не удается.
В самом начале(вне тела `try{}`) этой функции(где указано коментарием, что код работает) получить этот параметр удается.
Вопрос:
Что я упускаю из виду и каким образом можно получить этот параметр в нововызванной функции внутри тела `try{}`?
Если это сделать невозможно - то какие могут быть альтернативные реализации по решению данной задачи?

P.S. В данном случае используется библиотека для парсинга [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там 410-тым статусом помечается неторгуемое, так что нужен интерсептор

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

newCorporations().then(console.log).catch(console.error);

async function newCorporations() {
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://seo-gmbh.eu/invest/daily.php');
  const items = (data || {}).new_corporations || [];

  for (const item of items) {
    console.log(`-- ${item.finanzen_net} --`);
    let mainData;

    try {
      mainData = await parseNewCorporations(item);
    } catch (err) {}

    if (!mainData) {
      try {
        mainData = await getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv(item);
      } catch (err) {}
    }

    console.log(mainData);
  }
}

async function parseNewCorporations(iter) {
  const { data: html } = await axios.get(`https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/${iter.finanzen_net}-aktie`);
  const $ = cheerio.load(html, { decodeEntities: false });

  let price = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap').text();
  let currency = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap span').text();
  price = price.replace(currency, '').replace(',', '.');
  return { price, currency };
}

async function getAdditionPriceBilanzGuv(iter) {
  const ax = axios.create();
  ax.interceptors.response.use(
    null,
    (err) => {
      if (err.response && err.response.status === 410) {
        return Promise.resolve(err.response);
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  );
  const { data: html } = await ax.get(`https://www.finanzen.net/bilanz_guv/${iter.finanzen_net}`);
  const $ = cheerio.load(html, { decodeEntities: false });

  let price = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap').text();
  let currency = $('div.snapshot-headline div.col-sm-7 div.row.quotebox:first-child div.col-xs-5.col-sm-4.text-sm-right.text-nowrap span').text();
  price = price.replace(currency, '').replace(',', '.');
  return { price, currency };
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
-- asml_1 --
{ price: '450.00', currency: 'EUR' }
-- lukoil --
{ price: '58.40', currency: 'EUR' }
-- rocket_internet --
{ price: '23.64', currency: 'EUR' }
-- unilever_plc --
{ price: '', currency: '' }
```